# TypeScript: aliasing namespaced declarations in global namespace

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working on a TypeScript project (for the browser) where we're using a third party library with type definitions from DefinitelyTyped. In the type definitions for the library, its classes are declared like this:

```
declare namespace foo {
    export class Bar { ... }
    export class Baz { ... }
}
```

However, the actual implementation of the library places the classes in the global scope such that they can be referred to by just `Bar` and `Baz`. Because of this, using `foo.Bar` will compile, but not work at runtime.

To make it work, I would like to somehow bring all the exports of `foo` into the global namespace. I can't find any obvious ways to do this, so my best attempt so far is making an ambient declaration file saying

```
declare type Bar = foo.Bar;
declare const Bar: typeof foo.Bar;
```

and repeating for each exported class in `foo`. This allows me to instantiate the class, use it as a type, and call any static functions it may have, but declaring the same name twice for all exported types is not ideal. A shorter way of achieving the same thing seems to be

```
declare class Bar extends foo.Bar {}
```

but now I am needlessly extending the class, and the intent is not clear.

Is there a better way to alias/extract the exported types of `foo` as globals?

Comment: May I ask which package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a  dedicated syntax for extracting things from namespaces.

```
import Bar = foo.Bar;
```

Will bring the correspondingly named type, value, and or namespaces into scope under a single term named `Bar`.

Ensure that this is placed in an ambient context such as `d.ts` file or nested inside of a `declare` context.

If `foo` does not itself exist at runtime, then the declaration really needs to be fixed.

However, this is just a shorthand for your first work around, and what you should actually do is send a pull request to definitely typed to fix the declaration because it's broken.

Also note that your second solution involving extending `Bar` should not be used because it will change the behavior of your program in unexpected ways.

Comment: This will not work. This compiles to `var Bar = foo.Bar`, but `foo` is undefined.

Comment: @GregRos that would only be true if the OP's `declare namespace foo` did not correspond to a runtime value. That would make the declaration erroneous as it contains values.

Comment: That seems to indeed be the case, from the description of the problem. `Bar` is not really in a namespace called `foo`. It's in the global scope.

Comment: @GregRos ah, perhaps I misunderstood. I was under the impression that they were available in both qualified and unqualified contexts.

Comment: In the question: "Because of this, using foo.Bar will compile, but not work at runtime."

Comment: But, be that as it may, placing the above in an ambient context means that no runtime error will be introduced.

Comment: @GregRos thanks for bringing this to my attention, I have added a note about ambiance. If only we knew what library it was... :0

Comment: Yes, you're right, in a `.d.ts` file it will work. As for what library it was... there is no shortage of broken typings, sadly.

Comment: @GregRos indeed, but things are improving to a degree. I find that PRs to definitely typed are usually accepted with quickly. I've made a few dozen and only a poorly though out one was rejected.

Comment: The library in question is [gsap](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gsap). I imagine the typings are correct for some uses, but my situation is this: we're using an external, minified version of the library, but we want to consume it from an Angular/TS project that is bundled with Webpack while using its type definitions. Importing it as a module satisfies the compiler, but not Webpack (as the implementation module is missing). Using the namespace does not work at runtime (as the implementation declares things globally). Hence the ambient import trick.

Comment: @James sounds like you have a broken webpack build, as I know it supports your run time scenario, and you need to fix your declaration files.

Comment: You may be right, but we're using the default Angular CLI build configuration and would prefer to not stray from it. I'm also unsure how to actually fix it without adding the library itself to our dependencies.

Comment: @James the library _should_ be one of your dependencies. I don't care for how the Angular CLI does things and it wasn't part of the question